# Variable Tikhonov Parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

In the Tikhonov regularization problem, $\Vert Ax-b\Vert^{2}+\Vert\Gamma x\Vert^{2}$, with
$\Gamma=\alpha I$ .The solution from SVD is $x=VDU^\top$, where $A=U\Sigma V^\top$
and $D_{ii}=\dfrac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_i^2+\alpha^2}$, with
$\sigma_i$ given by the singular values from $\Sigma$.

The question? Is there a similar solution (in terms of SVD) when $\Gamma=\alpha_{i}I$, $i=1,...,$ number of rows.

Comment: How about substituting $y_i = \alpha_i x_i$ and using the SVD of the "rescaled" $A$?

Comment: I dont understand the solution can you be more specific to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tikhonov regularization in its most general form is the solution of the problem

$$\min_{\mathbf x}\|\mathbf A\mathbf x-\mathbf b\|^2+\alpha^2\|\mathbf L\mathbf x\|^2$$

or the problem

$$\min_{\mathbf x}\left\|\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf A\\ \alpha \mathbf L\end{pmatrix}\mathbf x-\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf b\\ \mathbf 0\end{pmatrix}\right\|$$

Lars Elden gave [a method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01932285) for converting this general Tikhonov problem into an equivalent "standard form" regularization problem. I assume in the sequel that $\mathbf L$ is invertible; for singular $\mathbf L$ (and in fact for rectangular $\mathbf L$ as well), refer to Elden's paper for the required transformations (which involves the use of the QR decomposition).

In particular, if we let $\mathbf y=\mathbf L\mathbf x$, one can see that an equivalent standard Tikhonov problem is

$$\min_{\mathbf x}\|\mathbf A\mathbf L^{-1}\mathbf y-\mathbf b\|^2+\alpha^2\|\mathbf y\|^2$$

from which you can use the usual formulae for Tikhonov regularization to solve for $\mathbf y$. From this, one obtains the solution to the general problem as $\mathbf x=\mathbf L^{-1}\mathbf y$.

Comment: I am looking for a similar formula like in standard Tikhonov solution through SVD, where there is an explicit solution dependence on $\alpha$, i.e $x(\alpha)$. The advantage with $x(\alpha)$ is that once the SVD of $A$ is computed
we can compute the solution for any $\alpha$, which is useful for
very big matrices - $A$. If there is a similar formula then I would
expect $x(\alpha_{i})$ for one SVD computation of $A$.

Comment: As I said, you can now use the formula you gave. The only difference is that youneed to compute the SVD of $\mathbf A\mathbf L^{-1}$ instead of just $\mathbf A$ (and it is easy to invert a diagonal matrix). After all the Tikhonov machinery, multiply the result with $\mathbf L^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$\min_x\left\|b - Ax \right\|_2 + \left\|\Gamma x\right\|_2=
\min_{x}
\left\|
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
             b \\
             0
\end{array} 
\right]
- \left[\begin{array}{c}
        A \\
        \Gamma \end{array}\right]x\right\|_2$

which is your original problem reformulated as a least squares problem. $x$ is a solution of the minimization problem if and only if it satisfies the normal equations
$\left(A^TA + \Gamma^T \Gamma\right) x = A^T b$. This is true for any $\Gamma$. For $\Gamma$ of full column rank we have a unique solution
$x = \left(A^TA + \Gamma^T \Gamma\right)^{-1} A^Tb$. Using this formula you can invoke the SVD of $A$ and study the effect of your regularization matrix $\Gamma^T \Gamma$ for various structures of $\Gamma$.